# Using DirectWrite to write text on a IDirect3DTexture9

Tags: directx11, directx9

I'm trying to write text using the DirectWrite API on a IDirect3DTexture9. I've heard that people were capable of doing this but I do not see directly how I can glue these two APIs together.

It seems I need a IDXGISurface to create a valid ID2D1RenderTarget (with which I can draw the text). I can get this by creating a surface for the Window. But I think the idea is that I use the IDirect3DTexture9 as a surface for the render target so that I can use whatever is drawn on it in my application.

I can get the underlying IDirect3DSurface9 from the IDrect3DTexture9 but then I have to convert it somehow to a IDXGISurface and this is where I'm stuck. Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: Commenting because I haven't ever done this, but it seems you need to use Direct3D 9Ex for this. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee913554(v=vs.85).aspx#interoperability_between_direct3d_9ex_and_dxgi_based_apis

Comment: If your application can count on the DirectWrite API being supported, then it can count on DirectX 11 and not use legacy Direct3D 9 at all in the first place. Otherwise, you'd need to use [DXGI Shared Surfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee913554.aspx) and ``Direct3D9Ex`` (see the section _Direct3D 9Ex Shared Surfaces Plus Manual Synchronization Helper_).